# Cannot get access token from Yahoo API using Ruby OAUTH Gem

Tags: ruby, api, oauth, yahoo-api

I have been trying for weeks to be able to get rosters from fantasy football leagues from Yahoo. I have written the below to get my access token from OAUTH.

STEP 1 (I already input the consumer key and consumer secret as variable before, I had the 3 urls also in the consumer.new statement but stack overflow will not let me include over 1 URL in my post.)

```
@consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(consumer_key, consumer_secret":request_token_path => URL ,:access_token_path  =>URL, :authorize_path =>URL)
```

STEP 2

```
@request_token = @consumer.get_request_token()
```

STEP 3 (This successfully gives me a URL and I can give permission for my yahoo fantasy football account, then it shows the user a code. I take this code and past it below as my oath verifier string.)

```
@request_token.authorize_url
sleep(30)

@token = OAuth::Token.new("ucjuyt",@request_token)

@access_token=OAuth::AccessToken.new(@consumer, token=@token, secret=@request_token.secret)

p @access_token.get("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20fantasysports.draftresults&diagnostics=true")
```

This returns the below error.

```
#<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true>
```

I am sure it has to do with how I request my access token but I cannot figure out how to get this thing working. I do not have a UI and am trying to run all of this in my Ruby code, is that OK? I have looked through Yahoos documentation and it has not helped me.

Comment: did you find a solution? I am facing almost the same problem

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
consumer_key= <your consumer key>
consumer_secret = <your consumer secret>
code = <the user code you got after you gave permission>
uri = URI('https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token')
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)

req.basic_auth consumer_key, consumer_secret

req.set_form_data({client_id: consumer_key, client_secret: consumer_secret, redirect_uri: 'oob', code: code, grant_type: 'authorization_code'})

sock = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
sock.use_ssl = true
res = sock.start {|http| http.request(req) }
puts res.body
access_token = JSON.parse(res.body)['access_token']
refresh_token = JSON.parse(res.body)['refresh_token']
```